# C++ overloading << with no const for the input object gives error, which goes away with const object

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading, constants

I have the following operator-overloading prototypes:

```
 ostream& operator<<(ostream & outputstream, my_arr& arr)

 my_arr operator+(const my_arr& left, const my_arr& right)
```

I call:

```
 cout << (arr1 + arr2);
```

This gives me the following compiler error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << operator+(const my_array&, const my_array&)((*(const my_array*)(& y)))’
```

This goes away if I change the signature of << to the following:

```
  ostream& operator<<(ostream & outputstream, const my_arr& arr)
```

I might be missing something basic here, but why does this happen? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are `my_array` and `my_arr` the same? Or is there an implicit conversion from `my_array` to `my_arr`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I have fixed it in the post. My code had it correct though and was getting the error as mentioned in the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when passing as reference, you cannot pass "temporary" (rvalue) objects such as the result of an addition. When passing a const reference, C++ rules allow passing temporaries because it's guaranteed they won't be written to.

Comment: @billz in your example, the operator most likely takes a `const std::string&`, which can bind to a temporary. But you are right about `my_arr` and `my_array`. I assume it is just a distracting typo.

Comment: I see, it's C4239 extension kicks in on VS2012 like hell, my apologies

Comment: @billz I think we are misunderstanding each other. In your example, `const T&` binds to a temporary, as expected. And OP's code works in the analogous case. It only fails when using a non const `T&`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I got it just now, on VS2012 extension C4239  allows binding to temporary object and I didn't notice it just now. my apologize.

Comment: @billz Oh I finally get it. Yes, I remember something about this VS extension. I just don't have VS, so I am blissfully immune to these quirks.

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned, the result of this is a temporary (an rvalue). You can also provide an overload of your output operation which has the form:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& outputstream, my_arr&& arr);
```

which `cout << (arr1 + arr2);` will then utilize.

Comment: I see, it's C4239 extension kicks in on VS2012 like hell, my apologies

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a typo in `operator+` also you need to pass `const my_arr` to `operator`

```
my_array operator+(const my_arr& left, const my_arr& right)
^^^^ should be my_arr                   ^^^ need to be const
```

Or you have to overload `operator<<` for `my_array`

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream & outputstream, my_arr& arr)
```

Otherwise the code just compiles and runs OK: [sample link](http://ideone.com/YYvd56)

Comment: No, the problem here is really about binding a reference to a temporary. Your example with `std::string` in other comments obviously doesn't apply since [`std::basic_string` defines `operator<<` as taking a const reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt). You should only take non-const ref if you intend to modify the object and then have to live with the fact that it won't bind to temporaries.

Comment: yes, your example also defines `operator<<` as taking a const ref. If you remove const, [it will not compile](http://ideone.com/ZQkTpE)